# How do I add a high score system to my turtle game?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm still pretty new to Python but I've been working on a game using turtle where you have to click a bunch of circles within a certain timeframe for a score. I want to create a high score system where people can decide on their usernames as well but everywhere I google is too complicated for me to understand, so I have no idea how to implement it into my code.

```
import turtle
from random import random, randint
import time

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
score=0

while True:
    diffSetting=int(input("Set the difficulty(1-5,1 being easiest and 5 being hardest): "))
    if diffSetting == 1:
        difficulty = 5
        break
    elif diffSetting == 2:
        difficulty = 8
        break
    elif diffSetting == 3:
        difficulty = 12
        break
    elif diffSetting == 4:
        difficulty = 16
        break
    elif diffSetting == 5:
        difficulty = 20
        break
    else:
        print("Please choose a difficulty setting between 1 to 5.")


def addscore():
    global score
    score += 1

def my_circle(color):

    if diffSetting==1:
        radius = (50)
    elif diffSetting==2:
        radius = (40)
    elif diffSetting==3:
        radius = (30)
    elif diffSetting==4:
        radius = (20)
    elif diffSetting==5:
        radius = (10)


    circle = turtle.Turtle('circle', visible=False)
    circle.shapesize(radius / CURSOR_SIZE)
    circle.color(color)
    circle.penup()

    while True:
        nx = randint(2 * radius - width // 2, width // 2 - radius * 2)
        ny = randint(2 * radius - height // 2, height // 2 - radius * 2)

        circle.goto(nx, ny)

        for other_radius, other_circle in circles:
            if circle.distance(other_circle) < 2 * max(radius, other_radius):
                break
        else:
            break

    circle.showturtle()
    circle.onclick(lambda x,y,t=circle: (circle.hideturtle(), addscore()))


    return radius, circle



screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("lightgreen")
screen.title("Speed Clicker")

width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

circles = []

gameLength = 30

startTime = time.time()
while True:
    time.sleep(1/difficulty)

    rgb = (random(), random(), random())

    timeTaken = time.time() - startTime

    circles.append(my_circle(rgb))
    screen.title('SCORE: {}, TIME LEFT: {}'.format(score,int(round(gameLength - timeTaken,0))))

    if time.time() - startTime > gameLength:
        for turtle in screen.turtles():
            turtle.reset()
        break


screen.title('GG! FINAL SCORE: {}'.format(score))

screen.mainloop()
```

I've been trying to keep the score in a text file but how would I keep the usernames?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to to store score in data base or file which you are moat prefer
2. After completing your game you must have to check you current score with stored score
3. If your current score is less then your stored score do nothing or restart game
4. Else you have to update your high score with previous stored score

**You Must Have Knowledge About Store Data**

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file in the same folder as this game.
2. Open the file and store the high score as a variable in your Python program. (0 if file is empty)
3. Every time the current score is greater than the high score, update the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'll write a small snippet, extend it to your wish.

First, create a file named 'scoreboard.txt' in the same folder as your game.
Do the following to get the details before starting the game.

```
f = open('scoreboard.txt', 'r')
name = f.readline()
high_score = int(f.readline())
f.close()
```

Check if they've got a highscore and get username (new_name) too:

```
if current_score > high_score:
    f = open('scoreboard.txt', 'w')
    f.write(new_name + '\n' + str(current_score))
    f.close()
```

NOTE: For the first time, fill the file with some random data like 'BOB' (press enter key), '24'.

Hope it helps!
Comment if there's any doubts!

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time! However I'm getting these errors:
    f.write(name + '\n' + score)
TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: and I'm also getting this:     score = int(f.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: use this:  f.write(name + '\n' + str(score))
For the next one, it just means that the next line is non-string (empty). open that file and type some random score in the second line (for the first time only).

Lemmie know if it helps

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems to work well now, but I have one final problem, and it's that this only seems to return the value of the most recent score rather than the highest one. Is there any way to only show the highest score?

Comment: I've edited the code to check for the high score. Check out!